# JQuery UI autocomplete for multiple search words in any order

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

The problem I have, say I have a title of:
"stackoverflow is the best site in the world"

It will find it if I do:
"stackoverflow is the"

But wont find:
"stackoverflow world"

Does anyone know if it is possible to use multiple words in JQuery UI's autocomplete?

Comment: It is definitely possible. You need a custom source function or you need your server to return results based on that requirement.

Comment: There are [several](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) [demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote) using multiple values. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Andrew.  I'm not needing to select multiple values, by return them.  In the demo your provided, type "middle" and you will see it returns "middle spotted woodpecker".  But if I type "middle wood", I get no results.  Its this problem I need to solve.

Comment: Hi Kevin.  Do you mean that the filtering will have to be done at server side? I.e. on each keypress, set the querystring to the source, separate each word, then query where contains word1 and word2 etc?  At present I only have a static array of values in Javascript.

Comment: @user287212: Are you using a client-side data source or are you filtering data on the server?

Comment: Hi Andrew.  I'm using a client-side javascript array. Cheers.